# Cannot access POST data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't access POST data in my node.js app. I'm also using express.

app.js:

```
app.post("/sent_message", function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body.message.name + " " + request.body.message.content);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/sent_message">
            <input type="text" name="message[name]">
            <textarea name="message[content]"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have the `bodyParser` middleware?

Comment: I'd try it without the brackets to see how it goes

Comment: @SLaks that was thee problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include `app.use(express.bodyParser());`.

Comment: `bodyParser` is not recommended.  Use `express.urlencoded()` and `express.json()` instead.  If you need to parse multipart form data (i.e. file uploads), you should use Busboy or Formidable.

Comment: @EthanBrown, and what does JSON or URL encodings have to do with a POST request?

Comment: A POST request transmits the fields (normally) as the body of the request.  That body is encoded in a format called "URL encoding", and that's what the `express.urlencoded()` middleware does.  (It's actually Connect middleware, but it's available through Express).  `express.json()` is not so commonly used, but some clients (especially AJAX requests) encode the body in JSON format instead of URL encoded.

Comment: `express.bodyParser()` simply includes `express.urlencoded()`, `express.json()`, and `express.multipart()`.  The reason it's not recommended is that `express.multipart()` is deprecated and will be removed entirely in the next version of Express.  Fortunately, Busboy and Formidable handle multipart encoding quite adroitly.